# New to Netbeans, trouble running multiple .java in same .pkg

Tags: java

So I recently started studying IT and currently we are working the basics of Java and using Netbeans 8.0.2 to do so.

I have several homework assignments that I enjoy doing a lot but I have got a question about the program.

I did the first assignment and it ran without any errors and showed me the output I was expecting, so I go on to make another .java mainclass file for my second assignment, within the same .pkg as my first assignment. But now every time I press the run button it only shows the first assignment in the output even though both are stated as mainclass files.

I know my code is correct because upon making a new project and doing the second assignment in a totally different project, it runs no problem and shows only the output of the second assignment.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Because it would be kind of annoying to create a new project for every assignment considering I'm doing 10+ a week.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you have `main` method in both classes?

Comment: This aricle might help you: https://www.thoughtco.com/using-multiple-main-classes-2034250

Comment: @TheScientificMethod yeah, both classes are main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the main class to execute in:

File > Project Properties > Run > Main Class

One example is available in this article:
https://www.thoughtco.com/using-multiple-main-classes-2034250